# Restoring MySQL database with different name on cPanel

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I created a database backup on cPanel, before things went a bit wrong.

We managed to screw up a live WordPress site, and would like to restore the the DB as a different name for the development site before launching it back to the live site.

Is there a way to restore a cPanel MySQL backup to a different database name?

Thanks.

Comment: What format does the backup file take. If its a SQL backup, you can edit the backup file and either add a `USE new_db_name;` or change the existing `USE` to the new name.

Comment: It's a SQL file inside a tar gzip file, and the only similarity I see in the DB name on cPanel and the backup is the filename.

Comment: so unzip it, amend it, then rezip it

Comment: Just looking for confirmation, as one of them is a live site that I can't screw up any further.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're saying "cPanel" so assuming that it's from cPanel's built-in backup utility so in .sql.gz format. You'll just need to gunzip (extract) that file, you'll find a .sql file inside of that. Simply create a new database, go into PHPMyAdmin, click on Import, select that .sql file (which you got after extraction), import it & you're done.

EDIT: Just to be on safe side, you can make sure that .sql file doesn't have something like "CREATE DATABASE". It shouldn't be there as per cPanel's standards but just be safe.